# 2 times a different class on tr and td with .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript:

```
$(".openPage").click(function() {
        alert(1);
    });

$(".openButton").click(function() {
        alert(2);
    });
```

My html:

```
<tr class='openPage'>
 <td></td>
 <td><button class='openButton'></button></td>
</tr>
```

When i click on my button inside the td the first function is fired instead of the function with alert(2). How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to `event.stopPropagation()` on the `button` item. That's all

```
$(".openPage").click(function() {
  alert(1);
});

$(".openButton").click(function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();   // The click won't propagate to .openPage parent
  alert(2);
});
```

Comment: Well, he described the problem as the first click being fired before the second. This wouldn't obviously have helped as this assumes the second fires first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the elemen is contained within the first one.

But you can, if you really need do:

```
$('.openPage').click(function(e, event) { 
       if ( $(e).hasClass('openButton) ) { 
            $(e).trigger('click');
       }
});
```

OR better

```
 var page = $('.openPage'); 
 page.click(function(e, event) { 
       if ( $(e) != page ) { 
            $(e).trigger('click');
       }
});
```

You could also try:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: What? `$('.openPage').click(function(e, event) { ` ... `e` is not the Element Object and `event` is not any *event* but undefined. You got this completely wrong. (Also, you have a typo in your code `'`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It was freestyle. Appearantly it is $(this) for e, and first argument is an event.